# SQL Server: Trace Flag 4135

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

What is the Trace Flag 4135 in SQL Server and what is the purpose of this flage? Should it be enabled? How to enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From this answer on serverfault:](https://serverfault.com/questions/37677/sql-server-2008-trace-flag-4135)

> The traceflag disables an optimization
>   in the query optimizer. The
>   optimization caused the issue
>   described in the KB article when you
>   try to insert into a table by
>   selecting from the table itself. As
>   turning on the traceflag could result
>   in a perf degradation, you only should
>   use it if you run into the issue
>   described in the KB article.

[KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960770)
[Thread on the topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/9ea718c2-e0e0-40cf-b12b-3269130448b7)